# Font boosting и проблемы со шрифтом в мобильных браузерах

Tags: css

Если добавить `width=device-width` это отключит font boosting?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Или же обязательно прописывать:

```
html{
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: почему бы Вам просто не попробовать и посмотреть что получится?

Comment: Ни то, ни другое не работает в последних версиях мобильного google chrome а также мобильного safari

Answer (score 1):

> `<meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
>
> В результате, дальнейшее уменьшение масштаба страницы станет
>   невозможным, и font boosting, призванный компенсировать это
>   уменьшение, естественным образом не запустится.

P.S.: пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь пользоваться поиском. Всего лишь 1-я ссылка из [выдачи google](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=font%20boosting) - статья из хабра "[Font boosting в мобильных браузерах](http://habrahabr.ru/post/214559/)"